# How To Run GCP Cloud Endpoints Locally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

So I am trying to figure out how to run GCP Cloud Endpoints locally. I have followed the instructions on the Github getting started with Cloud Endpoints located here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/main/endpoints/getting-started

However, the endpoints in the main.py which is what it tells us to run are hard coded. If I want to run an openapi.yaml like the one provided below, how would I run that to mimic what Im gonna push to the endpoints service

OpenApi.yaml

```
# Copyright 2021 Google LLC
#
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START swagger]
swagger: "2.0"
info:
description: "A simple Google Cloud Endpoints API example."
title: "Endpoints Example"
version: "1.0.0"
host: "echo-api.endpoints.YOUR-PROJECT-ID.cloud.goog"
# [END swagger]
consumes:
- "application/json"
produces:
- "application/json"
schemes:
# Uncomment the next line if you configure SSL for this API.
#- "https"
- "http"
paths:
"/echo":
 post:
   description: "Echo back a given message."
   operationId: "echo"
   produces:
   - "application/json"
   responses:
     200:
       description: "Echo"
       schema:
         $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
   parameters:
   - description: "Message to echo"
     in: body
     name: message
     required: true
     schema:
       $ref: "#/definitions/echoMessage"
   security:
   - api_key: []
"/auth/info/googlejwt":
 get:
   description: "Returns the requests' authentication information."
   operationId: "auth_info_google_jwt"
   produces:
   - "application/json"
   responses:
     200:
       description: "Authentication info."
       schema:
         $ref: "#/definitions/authInfoResponse"
   security:
   - google_jwt: []
   - gae_default_service_account: []
   - google_service_account: []
"/auth/info/googleidtoken":
 get:
   description: "Returns the requests' authentication information."
   operationId: "authInfoGoogleIdToken"
   produces:
   - "application/json"
   responses:
     200:
       description: "Authentication info."
       schema:
         $ref: "#/definitions/authInfoResponse"
   security:
   - google_id_token: []
"/auth/info/firebase":
 get:
   description: "Returns the requests' authentication information."
   operationId: "authInfoFirebase"
   produces:
   - "application/json"
   responses:
     200:
       description: "Authentication info."
       schema:
         $ref: "#/definitions/authInfoResponse"
   security:
   - firebase: []

definitions:
echoMessage:
 type: "object"
 properties:
   message:
     type: "string"
authInfoResponse:
 properties:
   id:
     type: "string"
   email:
     type: "string"
# [START securityDef]
securityDefinitions:
# This section configures basic authentication with an API key.
api_key:
 type: "apiKey"
 name: "key"
 in: "query"
# [END securityDef]
# This section configures authentication using Google API Service Accounts
# to sign a json web token. This is mostly used for server-to-server
# communication.
google_jwt:
 authorizationUrl: ""
 flow: "implicit"
 type: "oauth2"
 # This must match the 'iss' field in the JWT.
 x-google-issuer: "jwt-client.endpoints.sample.google.com"
 # Update this with your service account's email address.
 x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/jwk/YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL"
 # This must match the "aud" field in the JWT. You can add multiple audiences to accept JWTs from multiple clients.
 x-google-audiences: "echo.endpoints.sample.google.com"
# This section configures authentication using Google App Engine default
# service account to sign a json web token. This is mostly used for
# server-to-server communication.
gae_default_service_account:
 authorizationUrl: ""
 flow: "implicit"
 type: "oauth2"
 # Replace YOUR-CLIENT-PROJECT-ID with your client project ID.
 x-google-issuer: "YOUR-CLIENT-PROJECT-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
 # Replace YOUR-CLIENT-PROJECT-ID with your client project ID.
 x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/YOUR-CLIENT-PROJECT-ID@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
 # This must match the "aud" field in the JWT. You can add multiple audiences to accept JWTs from multiple clients.
 x-google-audiences: "echo.endpoints.sample.google.com"
# This section configures authentication using a service account
# to sign a json web token. This is mostly used for server-to-server
# communication.
google_service_account:
 authorizationUrl: ""
 flow: "implicit"
 type: "oauth2"
 # Replace YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL with your service account email.
 x-google-issuer: "YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL"
 # Replace YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL with your service account email.
 x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/YOUR-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-EMAIL"
 # This must match the "aud" field in the JWT. You can add multiple audiences to accept JWTs from multiple clients.
 x-google-audiences: "echo.endpoints.sample.google.com"
# This section configures authentication using Google OAuth2 ID Tokens.
# ID Tokens can be obtained using OAuth2 clients, and can be used to access
# your API on behalf of a particular user.
google_id_token:
 authorizationUrl: ""
 flow: "implicit"
 type: "oauth2"
 x-google-issuer: "https://accounts.google.com"
 x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs"
 # Your OAuth2 client's Client ID must be added here. You can add multiple client IDs to accept tokens form multiple clients.
 x-google-audiences: "YOUR-CLIENT-ID"
# This section configures authentication using Firebase Auth.
# [START firebaseAuth]
firebase:
 authorizationUrl: ""
 flow: "implicit"
 type: "oauth2"
 x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
 x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
 x-google-audiences: "YOUR-PROJECT-ID"
# [END firebaseAuth]
```

So just to be clear, what I want to be able to do is run endpoints locally in the same manner as I deploy them. Right now, I deploy Cloud Endpoints using an openapi.yaml file and I point that file at different cloud run services. Up until now we have been using nginx locally to mock the functionality of Cloud Run, but the problem is that we aren't able to mimic the authentication that Endpoints provides using nginx. So sometime our local environment is not consistent with our cloud environment.

Comment: Can you check the error logs? Are you getting any errors? If not, Can you try running this  `gcloud --verbosity=debug endpoints services deploy openapi.yaml` command to display debug information. Also check with this [Document](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/set-up-cloud-run-espv2) and [Troubleshooting Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/troubleshoot-config-deployment).

Comment: @SandeepVokkareni I am  able to deploy my endpoints fine. I just want to be able to deploy them locally using the openapi.yaml. Check out the example I included above. It would only work if I hard coded each one of the openapi endpoints into the main.py file